# Where do you put a lit match on Yom Tov?

Tags: yom-tov, how-to

Since you can't extinguish it, what do you do with it so that it won't burn or damage anything?

Comment: Anything not flammable should be fine, eg. aluminum or glass

Comment: @DoubleAA what if you put the flaming match on aluminum foil?

Comment: Note that this question is also applicable to shabbat. Many will not extinguish the match after lighting shabbat candles, as they have accepted the start of shabbat by lighting, and thus are forbidden from extinguishing the match. See [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/87131/jewish/How-to-Light-Shabbat-Candles.htm) for example.

Comment: @Feinstein83 Aluminum foil doesn't burn. That's why people put it in ovens, stoves and campfires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen people use a metal tray for this.  (Sometimes the tray also holds the candlesticks, if there's any concern they could be knocked over.)

If the candles are votive-style, in glass holders, then you can just drop the match in on top of the candle.  This is what I do in my *sukkah*, where I don't want to use taller tapers because of wind.

My dining-room table is close enough to my kitchen that if I'm careful I can walk over to the sink and drop the lit match in there, where it safely fizzles out on its own.  That might not work for everybody.

A suggestion from DanF in a comment is to wet the other end of the match (the part you hold) before lighting, and the match will self-extinguish.  (I have not tried this, but it makes sense.)

Comment: thanks monica.  what if you put the flaming match on the aluminum foil that you put the candlesticks on.  would it flame out harmlessly or would it burn up the foil God forbid?

Comment: I haven't tried using foil.  You could try the experiment when it's not yom tov (so if things go badly you can intervene).

Comment: Is there any halachic problem if the sink is wet?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok - how wet? If it extinguishes the match immediately, then "yes, there is a problem". If not, but it prevents the sink from getting stained (and the match may fizzle a bit) then I see no issue.

Comment: It does not burn the aluminum foil. I think you'd have to have a flame on the foil at a specific point for it to burn, anyway, but, I haven't experimented with that. Most matches are pretty much on their way to burning out on their own about half way down the stick. I think they design the matchsticks to do this, anyway. I've found in many cases, I can't light more than 1 candle, and the flame is out while I'm still holding the end of the match. Point is, in most cases, I don't need to put it anywhere. Another easy option is to wet the end of the match that you are using before striking it.

Comment: Thanks @DanF        Last Thursday night I put the flaming match in a 24 hour candle and I had problems, because the match wouldn't go out for about 48 minutes and the heat from the flaming match combined with the 24 hour candle cracked and burnt the glass of the 24 hour candle and I was afraid it cause a fire God forbid.

Comment: Adding a match to a burning candle literally adds wood to the fire!